# how do i get my loop to change what it does if value is negative or already in my sequences

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

Consider the sequence of integers given by

- x_0=0, x_n={x_(n−1)−n, only if (x_(n−1)−n) is not in the sequence already, and is greater than 0,
- otherwise x_n = {x_(n-1)+n

for n in range(0,100)

how do i get my loop to change what it does if value is negative or already in my sequences
this is what ive attemped so far but im a bit stuck now

```
s=0
sequence = [s]
for n in range(0,100):
    s+=1
    sequence_n = sequence[n-1] - sequence[n]
    sequence.append(sequence_n)
    print(sequence)
```

***edit***

have figured out neggative value issue but not the repeat issue

```
    import numpy as np
    x = np.zeros(11)
    x[0] = 1
    for n in range(1,11):
        x[n] = x[n-1] - n
        if x[n]<0:
             x[n] = x[n-1] + n
```

Comment: for `n==0` - `sequence[n-1]` is `sequence[-1]` wich is the last element of the sequence - wich is identical to `sequence[0]` which is the first element - and the difference of both is 0 - so you add another 0 into your sequence .... not sure I get what your problem is.  Might want to explain it _better_ and NOT inside the headline.

Comment: if your problem is dealing with possible duplicates (to meet x(_(n-1)-n) no in the sequence criteria) use a set instead of a list. Or convert the final list to a set.

Comment: @mquasar - that only works if order is of no importance.

Comment: @PatrickArtner yep, missed that point :)

Comment: `if new_value < 0:  do_one_thing else: do_other_thing` answers your question ... just scope it inside your loop ....

Comment: then this could work:

`if sequence_n not in sequence: sequence.append(sequence_n)`

Comment: changed my code to fix the neggative values but still stugling on fixing repeat values                                                                                                          `import numpy as np
x = np.zeros(11)
x[0] = 1
for n in range(1,11):
    x[n] = x[n-1] - n
    if x[n]<0:
         x[n] = x[n-1] + n `

Comment: fixed issue of duplicates by changing list to a set